# C# System.ArgumentException при переводе изображения в байты и обратно

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, byte

Всем привет! 
Я новичок в программировании и сегодня мой цель была реализовать простой медианный фильтр. Перевожу изображение в байты применяю медианный фильтр и когда пытаюсь из нового массива сделать изображение :
Вызвано исключение: "System.ArgumentException" в System.Drawing.dll
Если не менять исходный массив, то все ок. В чем проблема?

namespace mediana
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
    public static byte[] converterDemo(Image x)
    {
        ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(x, typeof(byte[]));
        return xByte;
    }
    private void byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        Image x = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(byteArrayIn));
        pictureBox2.Image = x;
    }
    public static byte Middle(byte[] mas)
    {

        if (mas[0] > mas[1] && mas[0] < mas[2] || mas[0] < mas[1] && mas[0] > mas[2])
        {
            return mas[0];
        }else
        if (mas[1] > mas[0] && mas[1] < mas[2] || mas[1] < mas[0] && mas[1] > mas[2])
        {
            return mas[1];
        }else
        {
            return mas[2];
        }
    }
    public  byte[] Mediana(byte[] arr)
    {
        byte[] three = new byte[3];
        byte[] dst = new byte[arr.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.Length-2); i++)
        {

            three[0] = arr[i];
            three[1] = arr[i + 1];
            three[2] = arr[i + 2];
            dst[i+1] = Middle(three);
        }
        dst[0] = arr[0];
        dst[arr.Length - 1] = arr[arr.Length - 2];
        return dst;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.JPG;*JPEG;*GIF;*PNG)|*.JPG;*JPEG;*GIF;*PNG|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
                byte[] source = converterDemo(pictureBox1.Image);
                byte[] res = Mediana(source);
                byteArrayToImage(res);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Невозможно открыть файл");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно понимаете, что означают байты, которые вы получили.

Байты, полученные вами — упакованный поток, вы не можете интерпретировать их как массив значений цвета. Соответственно вы меняете непонятно что.

Для начала, вам нужно работать не с `Image`, а с более специфическим классом `Bitmap`.

Для того, чтобы редактировать пиксели, у вас есть два пути. Либо вы работаете попиксельно через [`GetPixel(i, j)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`SetPixel(i, j, color)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel(v=vs.110).aspx). Это более простой, но и более медленный способ.

Либо вы получаете байты памяти картинки, и должны будете интерпретировать их самостоятельно в зависимости от формата. Код для этого есть в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3):

```
Bitmap bmp = ...;

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

// получаем адрес первой строки
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Заводим байтовый массив нужной блины
int nbytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
byte[] bytes = new byte[nbytes];

// копируем значения в массив
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, nbytes);

// --> тут обработка данных <--
// i-ая строка начинается по индексу i * bmpData.Stride
// длина в байтах одного пикселя зависит от вашего формата
// чаще всего у вас будет 24 или 32 бита на пиксель, то есть 3 или 4 байта

// копируем данные назад
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, nbytes);

// освобождаем данные
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```